# How to redirect any URL to my index.html using apache?

Tags: apache, redirect

I want my website to point at my index.html no matter what the URL is.
http://localhost/WebsiteName/
http://localhost/WebsiteName/whatever
http://localhost/WebsiteName/whatever/whatever-1/whatever-2/whatever-3/etc

By using this rewrite code in my apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

My URL works correctly when URL is any of these:
http://localhost/WebsiteName/
http://localhost/WebsiteName/whatever

But breaks when it is like this or further extended:
http://localhost/WebsiteName/whatever/
http://localhost/WebsiteName/whatever/whatever-1/whatever-2/whatever-3/etc

It acts as if there was another folder "whatever" in the directory whenever I use one of the URLs that break.

I don't want the URL to change, I just want it to point at my index.html no matter what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you have there, all of those url's should go to your index.html. The index.html is assumed to be at the DOCUMENT_ROOT.

I'm not sure what your problem is, but maybe instead of having a condition for rewriting non-files. Stop rewriting when it's a file. I notice any changes on my website, with either config, but maybe it can work for yours.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    ### If a uri leads to an actual file or directory (presumably with it's own index.html), then don't rewrite any further
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    ### everything else
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: The problem is that if my URL is "localhost" the page loads successfully, if the URL is "localhost/whatever" it loads correctly, but once you add another "/" after whatever it fails to load correctly. It behaves as if the localhost had a folder called "whatever" and it tries to load files from it, which fails because such folder doesn't exist. I am using the MVC pattern so I have js folder, views folder, and once it happens all files are overwritten with the index.html file